# What does the hash sign do in erlang?

Tags: erlang

What does the hash sign do in erlang?

```
record_to_string(#roster{us = {User, _Server},
         jid = JID,
         name = Name,
         subscription = Subscription,
         ask = Ask,
         askmessage = AskMessage}) ->
Username = ejabberd_odbc:escape(User).
....
.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They're used alongside [records](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html).

Comment: Take a look at http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#records and also http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html for the full explanation.

Answer (score 14):

Just for completeness (in case someone googles "Erlang Hash"):

The hash symbol can also be used to define an [integer with an arbitrary base](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id65900), as in

```erlang
16#deadbeef = 3735928559.
```

Answer (score 8):

They are related to Records in Erlang. Infact every operation like creation,accessing and updating records in Erlang are done using # http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-an-introduction-to-records/

Answer (score 5):

If a record is defined like this:

```
-record(record_name, {first_field, second_field}).
```

You can use the hash to access the record in various ways, among which:

```
% create a new record and put it in a variable
Record = #record_name{first_field = 1, second_field = 2},

% get only the second_field of Record
Field = Record#record_name.second_field,

% create a new record from Record, but with a different first_field
Record2 = Record#record_name{first_field = 5}.
```

Comment: I know it's an answered question but I put it here for future reference, as I needed this some time ago and only found links, not self-contained answers.

Links are useful, but as another comment pointed out, should not constitute a whole answer.

Answer (score 2):

As well as being part of the syntax for records and base denotation in numbers as previous answers have pointed out, as of Erlang R17, they are also used for maps. Map is a new key-value datatype introduced in R17 and they are expressed as: #{ Key => Value, ... }

I think the best source of information on maps is [this link](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0043.html). However, in release candidate 1 it seems not all functionality described there is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The Hash sign is used to work with records in erlang as noted by other answers. Here is an article that explains the syntax in a bit more detail. 
http://www.techtraits.com/Programming/2011/06/11/records-in-erlang/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Whilst this does theoretically answer the 
question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link just for reference.